# Javascript and phone camera

Tags: javascript

Is there some way by which I can open the phone camera using javascript or any other web development tools? Some results that I found were opening webcam using JavaScript. What changes do I need to make in the code to use phone camera?

Comment: What do you think a Webcam will be on a phone?

Comment: Have look into WebRTC https://webrtc.github.io/samples/